# How can I be sure $| f(x) - g(x)|$ gives the area at x independently of the signs of $g(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose I'm trying to find the area between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. I have noticed that, consistently, the integral of $f(x) - g(x)$ seems to give the area between these two functions. Now, the explanation seems to me to be that the absolute value of $f(x) - g(x)$ is the area bounded area between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. There's no problem understanding this if both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are positive. But in cases where both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ go in and out of positive and negative numbers, I can't wrap my head about this, especially in cases like the following graphs:

[$f(x) = x^3 \ ; \ g(x) = 4x^2-3x$ with absolute difference in green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxxxh.png)

[$f(x) = |x| - 3 \ ; \ g(x) = 2 \sin x$ with absolute difference in purple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CC8M.png)

The way it currently seems to me, is that the subtracting function, $-g(x)$, just happens to switch to the correct sign in time for $|f(x) - g(x)|$ to give the area at $x$. Am I missing something? I feel like I can't be sure the signs will always be such that $|f(x) - g(x)|$ gives the correct area at $x$.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but: $f(x) - g(x)$ is positive if $f$ is above $g$, but it is negative if $g$ is above $f$. $|f(x) - g(x)|$ is positive all the time because the absolute value is positive all the time (except for the points where it's zero).

Comment: Just think of $|f(x) - g(x)|$ as giving you the height of the vertical line segment between the two graphs over the point $x$ on the $x$-axis. The height is whichever of $f(x) - g(x) $ and $g(x) - f(x)$ that happens to be non-negative.

Comment: $f(x)-g(x)$ does switch signs exactly as you need them to under the absolute value, if you are not sure why, check the definition:
$$|f(x)-g(x)| = \begin{cases}f(x) - g(x) \ \ if \  f(x) \ge g(x) \\ g(x) - f(x)\ \  if \ f(x) < g(x)\end{cases}$$
This does not depend on the signs of the functions themselves at all, just the sign of the difference.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you this has been of great help!

Comment: @DavidMelo Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: I would call that distance and not area.